# Should I store a org.joda.time.YearMonth as date or as two columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I am storing values for specific months (with year) in my data model. For simplicity let's say I would be storing average temperatures for months like this:

```
|  month  | degreeCelsius |
+---------+---------------|
| 2010-01 |     5.2       |
| 2010-02 |     6         |
| 2010-03 |     6.8       |
|   ...   |     ...       |
```

Now I want to save this data to a PostgreSQL table and I wonder which data type to use for month. In my Java application I use an `org.joda.time.YearMonth` type to represent the month.

Basically I have two ideas: Either I use the `date` type which will also save a value for "day" which would be meaningless. Since the month is the primary key of the table it would be important that there are not two values inserted for the same month (but with different days) and that I can reliably search for the average temperature of a specific year-month. Thus I could create a constraint that enforces that the day must always be "1" and I could reliably search for `2010-02-01` if I want the value for February of 2010.

However keeping the day around feels a little awkward and someone else looking at the data model might be confused about the day part. So another idea would be to just split that type on two columns: `year` and `month`. Does this introduce new problems that I fail to see? Which solution is "better"/which drawbacks should I be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a date because that way you can use it directly when doing date arithmetic in sql queries.

Note that a good way to implement the check constraint you mentioned is to do `value=date_trunc('month', value)`. That way you guarantee there are no time values associated to the value. (EDIT: actually nevermind since postgres has a date datatype that doesn't accept time values. I'm used to oracle where we're stuck with a "date" datatype that is actually a timestamp)

Comment: Initially I thought "what possible data arithmetics could I probably want to to do" but then I remembered that I will select data ranges and sort results by date. While this is possible with other solutions it feels much less awkward with a date type. Thanks for also supplying the constraint code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like using dates for this. In this context, dates violate the Principle of Least Surprise.

So I'd store months as either one or two columns.  If you ever need to do date arithmetic--which in my experience is pretty unlikely--you can get either a date or a timestamp with concatenation and a cast.

The two critical things to watch are constraints and privileges.

**One column**

Store valid months in a table, and set a foreign key reference to it.

```
create table months (
  cal_month char(7) primary key
);

insert into months 
select left(generate_series('2010-01-01'::timestamp, 
                            '2100-12-01'::timestamp, 
                            '1 month')::text, 7);
```

You'll want to revoke permissions on that table from *almost* everybody.

```
create table avg_temps (
  cal_month char(7) primary key references months (cal_month),
  temp_c numeric(3, 1)
);

insert into avg_temps values
('2010-01', 5.2), ('2010-02', 6), ('2010-03', 6.8);
```

**Two columns**

You can put the base table in a different schema. (Also applies to the one-column solution.) This can make it simpler to control privileges.

```
create schema temperature;

create table temperature.avg_temps (
  cal_year integer not null
    check (cal_year between 2010 and 2100),
  cal_month integer not null
    check (cal_month between 1 and 12),
  temp_c numeric(3, 1)
);

insert into avg_temps values
(2010, 1, 5.2), (2010, 2, 6), (2010, 3, 6.8);
```

And use a view in the public schema to make it look tidy.

```
create view public.avg_temps as 
select cal_year || '-' || lpad(cal_month::text, 2, '0') as cal_month, temp_c
from temperature.avg_temps;
```

I prefer the one-column approach myself.